# How to send Status Codes Along with my Custom Class Using Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to make a log in system using spring. Problem is if username is not in the database I want to send a different status code and if username is in the database but password is wrong I want to send different status code. Because in my front end i am going to inform user using different alerts according to status code.

I cannot use `HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE` or something like that because my controller is returning a User(my custom class). It will either return User or null.

```
@GetMapping("/users")
    public User userLogin(@RequestParam String username,@RequestParam String password) {

        User user = userService.findByUsername(username);

        if(user==null) {
            return null;
        }

        if(user.getPassword().equals(password)) {
            return user;
        } else {
            return null;
        }

    }
```

Here I am trying to change status while returning nulls.

Comment: For security reasons I'd not tell the user whether the username or password are wrong (otherwise you'd help any attacker by telling him "oh, you've guessed a username, now just the correct password is missing"). Besides that you might want to consider throwing an exception instead of returning null.

Comment: Yeah. You are right.

Comment: Just to reiterate what @Thomas has just said. Absolutely any failure to authenticate, including any form of exception must return "Access Denied". Never leak the reason for failure, and never an exception string or stack trace. On the internet, most of your login attempts will be hackers probing your security I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can return **ResponseEntity** to meet your requirement

```
@GetMapping("/users")
public ResponseEntity<User> userLogin(@RequestParam String username,@RequestParam String password) {

    User user = userService.findByUsername(username);

    if(user==null) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(null,HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }

    if(user.getPassword().equals(password)) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(user,HttpStatus.OK);
    } else {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(null,HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Spring 5 introduced the ResponseStatusException class. We can create an instance of it providing an HttpStatus and optionally a reason  and a cause:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/{id}") public Foo findById(@PathVariable("id") Long id, HttpServletResponse response) {
    try {
        Foo resourceById = RestPreconditions.checkFound(service.findOne(id));

        eventPublisher.publishEvent(new SingleResourceRetrievedEvent(this, response));
        return resourceById;
     }
    catch (MyResourceNotFoundException exc) {
         throw new ResponseStatusException(
           HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "Foo Not Found", exc);
    } }
```

Maybe this is which you looking for?

Detail in https://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring#controlleradvice